# Bootloader in Assembly with Linux kernel

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel, bootloader

I'm on a school project, which is to make my own Bootloader.

This bootloader must have severals settings :

- The bootloader must load and run a linux kernel
- The bootloader must show a splashscreen while loading the kernel
- The bootloader must be able to run from the boot sector of the hard drive.

To realize this bootloader, I have the choice to code it in C or Assembly, I chose the Assembly. After many research my team and I, we failed to realized it yet. I managed to display an "Hello Word" and a "Loading the kernel" with the help of many and many tutorials.

So, we are (a little) lost, we don't really know how to put our kernel and bootloader in the same Virtual Machine (VMware). So we try with UltraISO (software to create .iso file) but it seems to doesn't work.

So guys I need some help here please because the deadline is coming soon and we are so disappointed. 
I love you already guys any help is welcomed.

(Sorry for my english you can lynched me after.)

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19743084

Comment: From the sound of things, you've taken on a project that's over your head. Talk to your instructor and see if you can reduce the scope of your project.

Comment: What hardware platform do yo use?

Comment: Check out LILO to get an initial idea !

Comment: From the same school, it's very difficult without helps. We need strong knowledge to complete this project...

Answer (score 1):

Boot loaders are a complex piece of software, especially ones that display splash screens. Since your team needs to create it from scratch, it may be difficult with a limited amount time.

I'd recommend reading [Bootloader](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bootloader) and [Rolling Your Own Bootloader](http://wiki.osdev.org/Rolling_Your_Own_Bootloader) from the [OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/). There's other resources there that can help you build a bootloader, too.

I hope this helps.